# How can I apply a jQuery function to all elements with the same ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am new to jQuery. I have the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#carousel').jcarousel();
});
```

It only applies to the first `ul` with `id="carousel"`, not for the others. How can I apply it to all elements which have the same ID?

HTML:

```
<!-- jQuery applies to this div -->
<div id="slideshow-carousel">
    <ul id="carousel" class="jcarousel jcarousel-skin-tango">
        <!-- ... -->
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- jQuery does not apply for this div -->
<div id="slideshow-carousel">
    <ul id="carousel" class="jcarousel jcarousel-skin-tango">
        <!-- ... -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you should avoid to use same id multiple times... use a class instead, eg <div class="myClass"></div> and $(".myClass")

Comment: Using the same ID for multiple controls? Thats a NO NO

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO :) +1 to them saying, you should create a class instead of id. also try doing a jsfiddle so we could continue from that and fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The IDs for elements are supposed to be **unique** in the `DOM`. Having the same ID for two or more elements is **not valid html**. To share functionality across elements, assign them a common class, rather than giving them the same ID. If you can't assign them a common class, the workaround below will allow you to select elements with the same id attribute:

Using the same ID **(If not possible to change ID)**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('[id=carousel]').jcarousel();
});
```

Using a common class **(Recommended way)**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery('.carousel').jcarousel();
});
```

Comment: If you add the explanation that having the same id multiple times on the same page is invalid HTML, then you have the best answer here.

Answer (score 9):

You can't have more than one element with the same Id, that's why is not working. You should use `class="caroussel"` instead.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.carousel').jcarousel();
});
```

Comment: `You can't have more than one element with the same Id` you can, it is just not valid HTML. :)

Answer (score 3):

In recent versions of jQuery, when you have multiple id's on the page, selector will return only the first 'id' that was found in the DOM. You should use class instead.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you should use class. You can not use id. Otherwise you can try the below code.

```
jQuery('ul').jcarousel();
```