# jQuery $(this) duplicate

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code really messes me up.. Could you help? There is 5 elements, with the `#newlinks`. In all `#newlinks`, there is childs of `a`. This code runs perfect on the first `#newlinks`, but after that one, it won't give the even `a`-elements a gray background.
`#newlinks`.

```
$(function(){
    var bg  = 0;
    $("#newlinks").children("a").each(function(){
        if(bg % 2 == 0){
            $(this).css("backgroundColor", "#F2F2F2");
            bg++;
        }else{
            bg++;
        }
    });
});
```

I have also tried this, but i guess it won't work, because `$(this)` could be both the newlinks-element selected and the a-element selected.

```
$(function(){
    var bg  = 0;
    $("#newlinks").each(function(){
        $(this).children("a").each(function(){
            if(bg % 2 == 0){
                $(this).css("backgroundColor", "#F2F2F2");
                bg++;
            }else{
                bg++;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: IDs (i.e `"newlink"`) **must** be unique on a page. Try using a class `<ul class="newlink">` instead, and use the class selector; `.newlink`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i apply Jquery function to all same id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274982/how-can-i-apply-jquery-function-to-all-same-id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not give the same ID for more than one elements. They must be unique.

You must use classes. So that `$(".newlinks")` selector should work.

Comment: You can also use the name="customName" property with a $("[name=customName]") selector.

Answer (score 2):

ID should be only one per page. Please change to class like `<div class="newlinks">` and then use the code below :

```
$(function(){
  $(".newlinks").children("a").each(function(index){
        if(index % 2 == 0){
            $(this).css("background", "#000000");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this [jssfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DZYyz/) :

```
$(function () {
    $("#newlinks a").each(function (index) {
        if (index % 2 == 0) {
            $(this).css("backgroundColor", "#F2F2F2");
        }
    });
});
```