# How to check if you've already entered the number in a dynamic input using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got stacked with this problem:

1. I just want to check if the number I entered is already entered in a dynamic inputs, then if it is, you cannot entered that number again, unless you delete it.
2. You can only enter a number up to the number of inputs *(e.g. if you have 10 inputs, then you can only enter NOT greater than 10)*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var arrayLen = $('.question').length;
  var numArray = [];
  var convertedArray;
  for(i = 1; i <= arrayLen; i++){
   numArray.push(i);
  }
 
  var currentVal;
  var maxAllowed = numArray[numArray.length - 1];
  var hasValue = [];
   
  $('.question').on('input', function(){
    currentVal = this.value;
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');
  }).bind('keyup', function(){
   if(currentVal <= maxAllowed){
     $("#result").html("available");
    } else{
     $("#result").html("not available");
      return false;
    }
  });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="trueFalse"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="shortAnswer"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="shortAnswer"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="description"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="trueFalse"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="trueFalse"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>

<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: You can't really do this via key events, because if there are ten inputs and one of them already contains the number "1" you wouldn't be able to enter the number "10" in another one (unless you pasted in "10" from the clipboard rather than typing a "1" followed by a "0").

Comment: IDs need to be unique, you can't have multiple `id="question[]"` inputs.

Comment: @nnnnnn Indeed Sir. So, maybe you have an answer to my question? because I think you're a JavaScript master.

Comment: @Barmar Why Sir? Please state it, together with your answer, so we can figure it out

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274982/how-can-i-apply-a-jquery-function-to-all-elements-with-the-same-id

Comment: @Barmar Nice link. Anyway, do you have any solution with my problem now?

Comment: @Barmar I've updated my code now, changed `id` into `class`.

Comment: @nnnnnn Any solution you have Sir?

Answer (score 0):

I did not do any validation or control what action to happen when your conditions are satisfied.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $inputObj = $("#input-div input[type=text]");
  var inputCount = $inputObj.length;

  // alert(inputCount);

  $('#question\\[\\]').on('input', function() {

    var $currInput = $(this);
    var currInputVal = $currInput.val();
    console.log(currInputVal);

    var cond1 = currInputVal < inputCount;
    var cond2 = isFreshInput($currInput);

    //console.log("cond2:" + cond2);
    if (cond1 === false || cond2 === false) {
      //TODO action when conditions are satisfied       
      $("#result").html("not available");
      alert("Either value already exist or number is too large");
    } else {
      $("#result").html("available");
    }

  });

  function isFreshInput($currInput) {

    var currInputVal = Number($currInput.val());
    var res = true;

    $inputObj.not($currInput).each(function() {

      let inputVal = Number($(this).val());

      console.log("inputVal:" + inputVal);


      if (currInputVal === inputVal) {
        console.log("input already exist!");
        $(this).css({
          "border": "solid red 1px"
        })
        res = false;
        // return false;  // break loop once found
      }
    });
    console.log("res:" + res);
    return res;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input-div">
  <input type="text" id="question[]" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="question[]" placeholder="trueFalse"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="question[]" placeholder="shortAnswer"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="question[]" placeholder="shortAnswer"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="question[]" placeholder="description"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="question[]" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="question[]" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="question[]" placeholder="trueFalse"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="question[]" placeholder="trueFalse"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="question[]" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="question[]" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
</div>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/33zeL2fa/9/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var arrayLen = $('input.question').length;
  var numArray = [];
  var convertedArray = [];
  for(i = 1; i <= arrayLen; i++){
   numArray.push(i);
  }

  $('input.question').keydown(function(e){
  var val = $(this).val();
   if(e.which === 8 || e.keyCode === 8){
     numArray.push(parseInt($(this).attr('newval')));
      $(this).removeAttr('newval');
    } else {
     val += e.key;
      if(numArray.indexOf(parseInt(val)) != -1){
        $('#result').html("available");
        $(this).attr('newval', e.key);
        numArray.splice(numArray.indexOf(parseInt(val)), 1);
      } else{
        $("#result").html("not available");
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="trueFalse"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="shortAnswer"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="shortAnswer"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="description"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="trueFalse"><br><br>

<span id="result"></span>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Don't do this in the `input` event, because when you're in the middle of typing an input it may match another input, and you won't let them finish editing it. You should use the `blur` event; this fires when they try to leave the input field.

When they change the input, loop through all the other inputs, and check if this value is the same as any of the others. If it is, show the error.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxAllowed = $(".question").length;
  $('.question').on('blur', function() {
    var currentVal = this.value.trim();
    if (currentVal == '') {
      return;
    }
    var msg = "Available";
    if (currentVal < 1 || currentVal > maxAllowed) {
      msg = "Not available";
    } else {
      $('.question').not(this).each(function() {
        if (this.value == currentVal) {
          msg = "Not available";
          return false; // Stop the .each loop
        }
      });
    }
    $("#result").text(msg);
    if (msg == "Not available") {
      $(this).focus(); // Put them back in the bad input field
      return false;
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="trueFalse"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="shortAnswer"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="shortAnswer"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="description"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="trueFalse"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="trueFalse"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="question" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>

<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: This is great. But, the second problem?

Comment: Isn't that what `currentVal > arrayLen` checks?

Comment: `$(this).focus();` // Put them back in the bad input field   <— this part is not working,

Comment: No, this doesn't work on submit, it's just on change.

Comment: I've changed it to use `blur` instead of `change`, because the old one allowed you to enter a duplicate if you pressed tab twice -- the second one isn't a change.

Comment: wait. let me check it first before you edit. Please provide all your code, create snippet every edit.

Comment: And please add the functionality where I can't enter a number if `currentVal > maxAllowed`

Comment: It's already there. Don't you see `if (currentVal < 1 || currentVal > maxAllowed) {`?

Comment: Try typing `20` and it won't let you leave.

Comment: What do you mean "it won't let you leave" ? It is working with `20`s, and I can leave the input and enter 20 again and again

Comment: I type `20` then TAB, it displays "Not available" and stays in that input.

Comment: are you sure with this? It displays "not available", but I can still go to other inputs and type 20 again

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for you. It works for me.

Comment: And what if I use mouse to focus in the other field?

Comment: The same thing happens for me.

Comment: I'm using Chrome, what are you using?

Comment: I'm using firefox.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work in FF. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046798/jquery-focus-fails-on-firefox