# Using bootstrap datepicker in django

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to StackOverflow.

I was following [this](https://codepen.io/ahsaan-566/pen/WPMjdq?editors=1010) piece of code to implement a bootstrap `datepicker`.
I encountered an error:

Date1 works but Date2 does not.
Can anyone explain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I apply a jQuery function to all elements with the same ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274982/how-can-i-apply-a-jquery-function-to-all-elements-with-the-same-id).  _Can anyone explain?_ The `id` selector (`#`) will assumes there is only one element with the given id, so it only finds one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `id` of your `div`, an `id` MUST be unique. So datepicker1, datepicker2...

Add class datepicker to your `div` like this `class="datepicker ..."`

Change `$("#datepicker")` by `$(".datepicker")` to have :

```
<label>Select Date 1: </label>
<div id="datepicker1" class="datepicker input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>

<label>Select Date 2:  </label>
<div id="datepicker2" class="datepicker input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>


$ (function () {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({ 
        autoclose: true, 
        todayHighlight: true
  }).datepicker('update', new Date());

});
```