# How do I create list the intended way I want

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I have the following scripts:

Does calculation for me and lists them

```
function fromPortIdChange() {
   fromportid = $('#fromPortId').val();
   console.log(fromportid);
   portIdRange(fromportid,toportid);
   listOfNumbers=[];
}

function toPortIdChange() {
   toportid = $('#toPortId').val();
   console.log(toportid);
   portIdRange(fromportid,toportid);
   listOfNumbers=[];
}

function portIdRange(fromportid, toportid) {
   fromportid = $('#fromPortId').val();
   toportid = $('#toPortId').val();
   fromportidlastvalueSliced = fromportid.slice(-5);
   interfaceNameLength = fromportid.length-1;
   interfaceName = fromportid.substring(0, interfaceNameLength);
   console.log("length: " +interfaceNameLength);
   console.log("interface name: " +interfaceName);
   fromportidlastvalue = fromportidlastvalueSliced.split('/')[2]
   console.log(fromportidlastvalue+ " FROM port id"); 
   console.log("range is " +fromportid+ " to " +toportid);
   toportidlastvalueSliced = toportid.slice(-5);
   toportidlastvalue = toportidlastvalueSliced.split('/')[2]
   console.log(toportidlastvalue+ " TO port id"); 
   console.log(typeof(toportidlastvalue));
   calculateRange(fromportidlastvalue, toportidlastvalue, interfaceName);
}

function calculateRange(fromportidlastvalue, toportidlastvalue, interfaceName) {
   fromportidlastvalue = parseInt(fromportidlastvalue);
   toportidlastvalue = parseInt(toportidlastvalue);
   console.log(fromportidlastvalue + " type is  " + typeof(fromportidlastvalue));
   console.log(toportidlastvalue + " type is  " + typeof(toportidlastvalue));
   currentValue = fromportidlastvalue;
   while(currentValue<=toportidlastvalue)
   {
      console.log(currentValue);
      listOfNumbers.push(interfaceName+currentValue);
      currentValue++;                
   }
   $('#port_range').val(listOfNumbers);
}
```

Here is the html involved:

The part it is on the page and the one I am going to clone

```
<div id = first>
 <div class="port">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="subnet_bit">From Port ID</label>
      <select id="fromPortId" class="custom-select mb-3" onchange="fromPortIdChange();">
      <option selected>Select</option>
      {% for items in righttable %}
      <option value={{items.0}}>{{items.0}}</option>
      {%endfor%}
      </select>  
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="subnet_bit">To Port ID</label>
      <select id="toPortId" class="custom-select mb-3" onchange="toPortIdChange();">
      <option selected>Select</option>
      {%for items in righttable%}
      <option value={{items.0}}>{{items.0}}</option>
      {%endfor%}
      </select>  
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="text-sm-center">
     <br />
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-rounded"><i class="dripicons-plus" onclick="addButton();"></i></button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The additional div i created for the clone to be in

```
<div id="morerows"></div>
```

This part is for the textarea

```
<p style="color:red;">If certain interface not needed, delete it</p> 
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-10">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="port_range">Port range</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="port_range" rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**righttable** comes from my django view

This script does the following: User choose `FortyGigabitEthernet2/0/1` from the drop down of `From Port ID` and `FortyGigabitEthernet2/0/5` from the drop down of `To Port ID`, it will list all the possible interface in `portrange` such as shown in the diagram, it lists `FortyGigabitEthernet2/0/1, FortyGigabitEthernet2/0/2,FortyGigabitEthernet2/0/3,FortyGigabitEthernet2/0/4,FortyGigabitEthernet2/0/5`

[image: List all the interfaces]

As you can see, there is a add button at the side. This is intended to to clone the drop down box for user to select other ports. Such as `TenGigabitEthernet1/0/1` for a cloned `From Port ID` and `TenGigabitEthernet1/0/3`. So the following `TenGigabitEthernet1/0/1, TenGigabitEthernet1/0/2, TenGigabitEthernet1/0/3` is add on to the existing `FortyGigabitEthernet2/0/1, FortyGigabitEthernet2/0/2,FortyGigabitEthernet2/0/3,FortyGigabitEthernet2/0/4,FortyGigabitEthernet2/0/5` in the text area of `Port Range`

For the cloning of the drop down box:

```
function addButton(){
    $('#first .port').clone().appendTo('#morerows')
}
```

Here comes the **issues**:

**1.** The add button works but i dont know is it lag or what. Sometime i have to click the add button multiple times before the cloned dropdown box appear.

**2.** The cloned drop down box are not working out like i want it to be. Like in the below picture. In 1st row we have `FortyGigabitEthernet2/0/1` and `Forty GigabitEthernet2/0/2`. This is listed in the `Port Range`. But for the 2nd row of `FortyGigabitEthernet2/0/4` and `FortyGigabitEthernet2/0/5`, it is not listed in the `Port Range`

[image]

Sorry for a very long post but is there anyway for me to achieve what I need. Appreciate if someone can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't find the DIV that you're cloning. Make sure you're not creating duplicate IDs when you do that.

Comment: I'm so sorry about that. I just edited my post. How do i ensure the clone drop down does not have the same id ?

Comment: Use classes instead of IDs.

Comment: What do you mean by that?  Can you give me a example? Sorry about that, im still a beginner in this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274982/how-can-i-apply-a-jquery-function-to-all-elements-with-the-same-id

Comment: I used classes but the functions are not running on the cloned class div though